# What is the difference between "modules" and "functionals" in PyTorch?

Tags: pytorch

In PyTorch, we have [`torch.nn.funtional`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.functional.html) and [`torch.nn`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html), and the classes/functions within the former are typically referred to as "functions" while the latter as "modules".

There seems to be a lot of overlap between the two, so I'm wondering what are each used for and what their differences are?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the differences:

- [`torch.nn.functional`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.functional.html) is the base functional interface (in terms of programming paradigm) to apply PyTorch operators on `torch.Tensor`.
- [`torch.nn`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html) contains the wrapper `nn.Module` that provide a object-oriented interface to those operators.

So indeed there is a complete overlap, modules are a different way of accessing the operators provided by those functions.

Every single tensor operator in PyTorch is available in the form of a function and its wrapper class. For instance `F.conv2d`, `F.relu`, `F.dropout`, `F.batch_norm` etc... have corresponding modules `nn.Conv2d`, `nn.ReLU`, `nn.Dropout`, `nn.BatchNorm2d`, `2d`, `3d`.

Comment: I'm also not too well-versed with Python (I mostly use C++) by the way, so I may not understand the python programming paradigm as well as I should. Is it correct to say that `torch.nn.functional` is lower level than `torch.nn`? When should we choose one over the other?

Comment: In the way, PyTorch was built and organized. Yes, functions are what contain the base implementation for a given operator. While `nn.Module` are classes that wrap this function, by that I mean they exclusively use a function themselves without introducing additional logic. What you can do with the OOP interface you can do the functional interface since the former is built on top of the latter. In practice `nn.Module` have the advantage of benefiting from an initializer (as with the OOP paradigm in C++)...

Comment: ... that is you can define the operator's parameters once with the class init function, then call a method on it (most often `__call__` to perform the operation... which will effectively call the underlying functional interface implementation itself, with the arguments defined earlier in the class initialization. I hope this gives you a little better outlook on how this works out ;). If you use the operators several times, it's usually good practice to utilize the class over the function as it is more cumbersome to call.